# Batch - For - Rename Files in several subfolders with count

Tags: batch-file, cmd

We have many Oracle-Database-Client versions in our company.

The *tnsnames.ora* will be changed often.

I like to create a package (batch) to backup (rename) the present file in all versions of Oracle Client (if there are two or more versions installed) and after that, copy the new file.

My script for now looks so:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0
set OracleDir="%SystemDrive%\oracle\product"

for /d %%i in (%OracleDir%\*) do (
  set dir=%%i\client_1\network\admin\

    PushD !dir:\\=\!\

    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od tnsnames.ora') do (
    rename "%%a" "tnsnames-%Date%-Backup-!count!.bak"
    )
    set /a count+=1
IF NOT EXIST "%%i\client_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora" ( 
copy "%~dp0tnsnames.ora" "%%i\client_1\network\admin\" /Y
)
)
endlocal
```

So far so good. But the script will only create a backupfile once. 
But it must create a new "**tnsnames-%Date%-Backup-!count!.bak**" everytime I run the script.
Hope you know what I mean?

I'm sure, i need a jump point somewhere but no idea where.

Comment: Are you sure that your `%DATE%` variable doesn't use disallowed file name characters like **`\\`**?

Comment: its OK. Because german format: 31.08.2017 :)

Comment: You are aware that the format is very easily user changed so using `%DATE%` is prone to unknown factors. As a side note, using **`.`** in file names is also in my opinion crazy. Windows Explorer defaults to not showing extensions for known file types so using **`.`**  can easily confuse an end user into believing that part of the file name is actually it's extension.

Comment: Your absolut right. I don't think about it. But we have english users too.
Now i try that:
set ToDaysDate=%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%
and set the filename with this variable. ;)

But the time formatting is another issue. 
Need a mix of these two: %time:~,-6% and %Time::=.%

With the dots, your right too.
I'm leaving the extensions at .ora.
Thank you

Comment: Little bit of googling....

What do you think about it:
set ToDaysDate=%date:~-4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%--%time:~-11,2%-%time:~-8,2%

Gives me that: tnsnames-2017-08-31--21-57.ora

Answer (score 0):

IMO you did overcomplicate things.

The inner for is useless doing a dir for a file at a fixed location. This is better checked with an if exist.

If you then rename that file the next if is also useless, it can't exist - you just renamed it (better check if the rename was succesful)

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0
set OracleDir="%SystemDrive%\oracle\product"

for /d %%i in (%OracleDir%\*) do (
    set "dir=%%i\client_1\network\admin\"
    PushD "!dir:\\=\!\" || (Echo couldn't pushd "!dir:\\=\!\"&Pause)
    Set "Stamp=!Date!.!Time:~,2!.!Time:~2,2!"
    if exist tnsnames.ora if not exist "tnsnames-!Stamp!-Backup.bak" (
        rename tnsnames.ora "tnsnames-!Stamp!-Backup-!count!.bak"
    )
    set /a count+=1
    if not exist  tnsnames.ora copy "%~dp0tnsnames.ora" "!dir!"
    PopD
)
endlocal
```

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

Thanks for you answer.

But your syntax will only make one backup file too... If one backupfile exist, no more will be created.

Example: In Folder are:

tnsnames.ora tnsnames-31.08.2017-Backup-1.bak

When i run the script it must backup the tnsnames.ora to tnsnames-31.08.2017-Backup-2.bak and so on. Need more revisions from this file.

Thank you

Comment: Well It wasn quite clear to me what the counter should do. If you want a backup whenever the batch is run, why don't you add the time also `%Time::=.%` ?

Comment: The counter should represent the revision. Ok, time is a good deal. 
This format will be nice: %time:~,-6%
But than the collon is dissallowed.

A mix with %time:~,-6% and %Time::=.% would be nice.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, see above changes with variable `Stamp`